# JavaScript Jquery how to split any character different from text

Tags: javascript, split

i have this script: 
`val.split( /(?:,.| )+/ )`

and i need to split any character different from letter, like new line, white space, "tab" or dot... etc

I know you cannot write all characters, so give me one good example.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[\W_0-9]` should cover them all.

`\W`: Everything which is not a letter, a number, or the underscore; then adding the _ and all digits from 0-9. This has the benefit of covering non ASCII letters such as é ü etc...

Comment: Cover what? What do the various characters do?

Comment: \W = everything which is not a letter, a number, or the underscrore; then adding the _ and all digits from 0-9. This has the benefit of covering non ASCII letters such as é ü etc

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest, possibly:

```
val.split(/\W/);
```

References:

- [RegExp, at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Careful about the digits and `_` excluded in `\W`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` to create a range of possible characters and prefix `[^` to invert the range. So:

```
val.split(/[^a-z]+/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myString = "Hello, I'm a string that will lose all my non-letter characters (including 1, 2, and 3, and all commas... everything)"
myString.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi, '').split(" ");
```

It'll split a string into an array, stripping out all non-letter characters as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

> I know you cannot write all characters, so give me one good example.

In character classes, you can enumerate characters with a `-`; like so: `[a-zA-Z]`

> and i need to split any character different from letter, like new line, white space, "tab" or dot... etc

You can negate a group of characters like this: `[^a-zA-Z]`

> I have this script: `val.split( /(?:,.| )+/ )`

Which can now be this script: `val.split(/[^a-zA-Z]+/)`